# How to automate the update of Web Service URL in Azure API management

Tags: azure, gitlab, microservices, gitlab-ci, azure-aks

How to automate the update of Web Service URL in Azure API management when CI/CD pipeline executes resulting in change of external IP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Open API specs from your APIs and use REST API / Powershell to update or add routes in API Management. There's also an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stephane-eyskens.apim) but I am not sure if it's updated or not. You can read more about in here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit